# Is it possible to redevelop jQuery-based website to SAPUI5?

Tags: jquery, sapui5

Our webpage is completely based on jQuery/jQueryUI/dHTMLx and some additional small libraries. Now they want me to do every upcoming developments in SAPUI5. Is that possible in some normal way? Is there any proper workaround to do that?

EDIT: okay, I will try to refine my question. We have cca 50000 lines of code in frontend. We will NOT rewrite everything into SAPUI5. The intention is to do new additional developments in SAPUI5. My question is: does it have any meaning to mix together existing libraries with a new framework?

Answer (score 1):

SAPUI5 contains many third-party libraries and jQuery/UI are also included.
But when someone asks you to redevelop an existing app in UI5, they would expect you to replace the current UI with UI5's controls, and make use of UI5 concepts. So I do not see any short-cut here, rather than doing real re-development. Not sure what do you mean by "normal way".

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the surface elements, I am sure that SAPUI5 covers all JQueryUI elements and because SAPUI5 is based on JQuery, you can continue to use all functionalities.